# ¿Cómo enumerar filas de un DataTable Js?

Tags: jquery, datatables

Estoy buscando una forma de enumerar las filas(registros) que llegan a mi tabla mediante petición ajax, sin tener que pasarle los registros enumerados desde la api(laravel).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi script:

```
function getAlumnos() {
let grado = $('#grado').val();
let seccion = $('#seccion').val();

$("#alumnos").DataTable({
    "language": {
        'url' : '//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.19/i18n/Spanish.json'
    },
    "aaSorting": [],
    "serverSide": true,
    "destroy": true,
    "paging": false,
    "searching": false,
    "ordering": false,
    "ajax": "/asistencia/dtalumnos/"+grado+"/"+seccion,
    "columns": [
        {data: 'nombres'},
        {data: 'apellidos'},
        {data: 'asistencia'},
        {data: 'tardanza'},
        {data: 'falta'}
    ]
});
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que buscas se llama `index column` dentro de la [documentación](https://datatables.net/) de los `Datatables`.

Agregas un `th` vacio a tu tabla:

```
<thead>
<tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Position</th>
    <th>Office</th>
    <th>Age</th>
    <th>Salary</th>
</tr>
</thead>
```

Creas tu `DataTable` y defines que en la `columna 0` (la que creaste) no se pueda buscar y ordenar. Posteriormente se hace un ciclo donde se aumenta el valor de `i+1` y con esto puedes hacer la `indexación` de tu `tabla`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var t = $('#example').DataTable( {
        "columnDefs": [ {
            "searchable": false,
            "orderable": false,
            "targets": 0
        } ],
        "order": [[ 1, 'asc' ]]
    } );

    t.on( 'order.dt search.dt', function () {
        t.column(0, {search:'applied', order:'applied'}).nodes().each( function (cell, i) {
            cell.innerHTML = i+1;
        } );
    } ).draw();
} );
```

Resultado:

[image: DataTable]

Referencia: [Index Column](https://datatables.net/examples/api/counter_columns.html)